# What is the SHV stat in NBA Jam?

Tags: ps3, nba-jam-2010

What does SHV mean?  Shove?  If so, getting shoved or shoving?

I'm referring to NBA Jam for PS3.  SHV seems to replace the stat Injuries (or Injured, or something like that) for the original arcade game.

Comment: I believe it's shove and shove *counters* (where you dodge/counter a shove by an enemy player). My knowledge is a little out of date however, I used to play this on Sega Mega Drive hehe.